# Django create instances from class attributes

Tags: django

Suppose such a Topic Model Table

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

As the structure indicates, `text`, `data_added`, `owner` are class level attribute.

However, Django is capable of creating instance from the class attributes

```
In [21]: Topic.objects.create(text='Celery', owner_id=1)
Out[21]: <Topic: Celery>
In [34]: celery = Topic.objects.get(pk=22)
In [35]: isinstance(celery, Topic)
Out[35]: True
```

I assume there should be initiating process `def __init__()`

How Django accomplish such an amazing task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` is defined on the `Model` class [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/392963e8e4605ff6da770450623ceaef0892cab7/django/db/models/base.py#L384) in the Django source.

Since you derive from `Model`, you're getting that `__init__` from the superclass.

When you call `QuerySet.get()`, it eventually (through some hoops within `QuerySet`) calls [`Model.from_db()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/392963e8e4605ff6da770450623ceaef0892cab7/django/db/models/base.py#L488-L499) which calls the `__init__` method (line 496).

Also, to elaborate: Even if `text`, `date_added` and `owner` *look* like class attributes, they end up not being present on the final model subclass, since the [`ModelBase` metaclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/392963e8e4605ff6da770450623ceaef0892cab7/django/db/models/base.py#L61) gathers them up into the new model subclass's `_meta` class (which is an instance of [`Options`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/392963e8e4605ff6da770450623ceaef0892cab7/django/db/models/options.py)).